# Раскольников решил убить старуху процентщицу / старуху-процентщицу

Tags: дефис

Как правильно?

> Раскольников решил убить старуху процентщицу.

> Раскольников решил убить старуху-процентщицу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оба варианта верны, но дефис предпочтительнее:

*Раскольников решил убить старуху-процентщицу*.

Хотя и раздельное написание не будет ошибкой.

**[«Грамота.ру»](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=282856#:%7E:text=%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%22%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%83%D1%85%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0%22%20%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%20%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%81%2C,%D0%94%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%20(%22%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%83%D1%85%D0%B0%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0%22))**:

> Здравствуйте!
> Сочетание "старуха-процентщица" пишется через дефис, т. к. процентщица - приложение. Но в тексте Ф. М. Достоевского пишется раздельно ("старуха процентщица").
> В разных литературоведческих работах можно встретить оба варианта написания. Скажите, что предпочтительнее? Не будет ли считаться ошибкой, если я напишу раздельно? Спасибо.
>
> ---
>
> **Ответ справочной службы русского языка**
>
> ---
>
> Согласно официально действующим сейчас «Правилам русской орфографии и пунктуации» 1956 года, между определяемым словом и стоящим перед ним однословным приложением, которое может быть приравнено по значению к прилагательному, дефис не пишется: красавица зима (=красивая зима), старик отец (=старый отец), бедняк сапожник (=бедный сапожник). Такое написание предлагается и в справочниках Д. Э. Розенталя, которые полностью опираются на действующие правила. Этим правилом, очевидно, руководствовались редакторы и корректоры, готовившие издания Ф. М. Достоевского.
>
> Однако теперь рекомендации лингвистов изменились. В «Русском орфографическом словаре» РАН (4-е изд., М., 2012) и полном академическом справочнике «Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации» (М., 2006), которые подготовлены сотрудниками Института русского языка им. В. В. Виноградова РАН, предлагается дефисное написание подобных сочетаний: старик-отец, красавица-дочка. Такое написание, хотя и вступает в противоречие с действующими правилами, тем не менее соответствует современной практике письма и более последовательно и логично отражает применение дефиса при написании сочетаний существительных.
>
> Таким образом, сейчас предпочтительно дефисное написание. Но раздельное написание не ошибка (формально оно соответствует правилам).

Comment: Мне кажется, сто здесь нет определительного значения – старая процентщица. Это единый образ, где слова равноправны.  Именно поэтому дефисное написание представляется более верным, а не из-за того, что правила изменились.  Произношение без паузы.

Comment: Суперответ таки!

Comment: @ Леопольд-мэтр  Ответ хороший, но еще нужен суперслух  и суперпонимание смысла. А голос за вопрос — от меня.  Ну и ответ тоже.

Comment: @Sharon а мне кажется, что старуха, как раз с упором на старая, потому что старуха вообще произошло от старая, также как и старик. Другие названия дед и баба, при том, что баба - это вообще уважаемый человек(бабай), в то время как дед, скорее всего указание тоже на немощь. http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/2324144-ded-kakaja-etimologija-i-proishozhdenie-slova-ded.html

Comment: @Буратино Старик — нейтральное слово, только основной признак лица, а старуха —  слово с дополнительной экспрессией, это уже характер, а не только признак. Старухи вечно злые и капризные.

Answer (score 2):

**О старухе-процентщице**

**СЕМАНТИКА**

**ПРОЦЕНТЩИК**, -а; м. **Устар**. Тот, кто даёт деньги в долг под большие проценты; ростовщик. <Процентщица, -ы; ж. Старуха-процентщица (персонаж романа Достоевского "Преступление и наказание").

**Устарело** словечко, сейчас ростовщик?

**РОСТОВЩИК**, -а; м. **Устар**. Тот, кто даёт деньги в долг под большие проценты, в рост. <Ростовщица, -ы; ж.

**Тоже устарело?**

Да, только **[ростовщичество](https://brobank.ru/rostovshchik/#respektabelnye-kontory-rostovshhikov)**  не устарело и  существует наряду с **банковскими** организациями и их **кредитными** продуктами. Но ростовщиков редко называют именно таким словом, оно вызывает **недоверие** у многих людей.

Поэтому существуют такие **микрофинансовые** организации, которые выдают деньги в рост заемщикам.

Сейчас термин «ростовщик» используется **очень редко.** Но в Гражданском Кодексе РФ в статье 809 указано, что если проценты по займу превышают стандартные ставки, то такая деятельность считается **ростовщической**.

В Древней Руси ростовщическая деятельность считалась **позорной.**

**Старуха-процентщица** в романе — это единый **смысловой образ**. Итог жизни — лихоимство и мироедство. **Бессмысленная жизнь!** Вот на кого покушается Раскольников.

**ПРОИЗНОШЕНИЕ**

(1) **СтарУха  процЕнтщица** — словосочетание, раздельное произношение, два ударения.

(2) **Старуха-процЕнтщица**  —  сущ. + приложение,  слитное произношение, основное и вспомогательное ударение.

(3) **СтарУха-процЕнтщица** — два существительных, слитное произношение, два ударения (как в слове вопросы-ответы).

**ВЫВОД**

Мне кажется, что здесь нет **определительного** значения – старая процентщица. Это **единый образ**, где слова равноправны. Именно поэтому дефисное написание представляется **более верным**, а не из-за того, что правила изменились. Произношение без паузы.